# Hide caret to read only text input in Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, caret

I am trying to hide caret in a read only text field in Firefox and IE9.

How to do this?

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/qbwyrkpp/)

This is working as expected in Chrome but not in firefox and IE9.

Currently, I am solving this using javascript

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[readonly]');
console.dir(input);
input.onfocus = function (e) {
    var el = e.currentTarget;
    el.blur();
}
```

I am looking for pure css solution.

Comment: i am using firefox. it works too

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira when you click/focus on the textbox, you can see the caret..

Comment: oh the cursor. sorry, i didnt know caret

Comment: You can use [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: @anpsmn doesn't work for IE9

Comment: @Mr_Green Oh my bad. I looked at the browser compatibility for SVG than HTML content and thought it works from IE 9.